# Breadboard / Jumper Cables Instead of Arduino Uno Shield

Tags: arduino, breadboard

I have the following hardware that mounts on top of Arduino Uno:

https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/control-hvac-infrared-devices-from-the-internet-with-ir-remote/

I need to connect it to Raspberry Pi, which can be done using this shield:

https://www.cooking-hacks.com/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shield-connection-bridge

The shield will take a while to arrive, and I want to start prototyping ASAP. Can I use a regular breadboard (or even simple jumper cables) instead of the shield, or are there additional HW requirements (capacitors, resistors, etc.) that should be taken into account?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update if you had any luck?

Answer (score 2):

The IR board claims it is compatible with the RPI gpio, which is good, but it's not clear that means it can directly handle the 3V3 from the RPI when arduinos have 5V gpio. That might be part of the reason for the compatibility shield.

The other part of it is the device is intended for an arduino and the software for the compatibility shield includes the "arduPi library which allows to use Raspberry with the same code used in Arduino."

If the voltage isn't an issue you could certainly try wiring the rpi gpio pins to the IR board and power it with 5V and see if you can get it to work.

[Here is the IR remote schematic](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/media/cooking/images/documentation/tutorial_ir/HVACinfrared3.pdf) from the [page that has the details on the IR board](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/control-hvac-infrared-devices-from-the-internet-with-ir-remote/#electrical-features).

Certainly it would have been easier and cheaper to use an arduino uno, but perhaps you want wifi.